# What is the alternative for setSplitLate() method in iText7?

Tags: java, pdf, split, itext, itext7

[image]I am migrating from iText5 to iText7 and I am stuck at a point where I have to implement the table property 'setSplitLate(false)'. But there is no such method in iText7 for the table. I want to give options to the user whether he wants to split the row or not. I was using the following code in iText5.

```
if(isSplitRowOnFirstPage){
   table.setSplitLate(false);
}
```

Where isSplitRowOnFirstPage is the boolean value entered by the user.
How can I achieve the described functionality?

I have attached the output of functionality in iText5 using mentioned method.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: does [setKeepTogether(boolean keepTogether)](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/BlockElement.html#setKeepTogether-boolean-) fix your issue?

Comment: you can find some examples with it on [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/tables)

Comment: setKeepTogether() is not doing the work I am expecting.Single row of my table is can grow multiple pages on basis of dynamic data.In that case, the mentioned method will not work as expected.

Comment: can you provide with a bit more of code with what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the only code that I am using. After creating the table structure I am setting the property mentioned above on the basis of boolean value passed by the user. The one use case is: If a row has some agreement kind of text and a signature area, and only the signature area get split to the multiple the next page. User want to start the whole table from new page. I have already mentioned how it was achieved in iText5, but I have no idea in iText7 to do the same.

Comment: can you provide with some screenshots of what you want to achieve? or the itext5 code you're using (more than just the if statement)?

Comment: @AndréLemos I have attached the image which differentiates between the output on the basis of `table.setSplitLate()` property. In the left side PDF, flow is not entering the if loop. i.e. setSplitLate(true) which is the default value. In right-side PDF, the flow is entering in the if loop and split late property is set to be false. i.e. setSplitLate(false). I am not doing anything different here. I am simply adding 4 rows in which any row may split due to large content. and before printing the table I am setting the property using the mentioned if loop.